# Condition on $a$ for $(x^2+x)^2+a(x^2+x)+4=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Find the set of values of $a$ if $$(x^2+x)^2+a(x^2+x)+4=0$$ has

$(i)$ All four real and distinct roots

$(ii)$ Four roots in which only two roots are real and distinct.

$(iii)$ All four imaginary roots

$(iv)$ Four real roots in which only two are equal.

Now if I set $x^2+x=t$ then even if $t^2+at+4=0$ has real roots in is not necessary that $(x^2+x)^2+a(x^2+x)+4=0$ will have real roots too.  So how to derive the condition on a?

Could someone give me some direction?

Comment: What if $t$ is not real.  What does $x^2 + x = t$ tell you about $x$ in this case?  Can you find a value of $t$ where $x^2 + x = t$ has a double root?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we want to find the values of $a$ such that there are four real and distinct roots (values of $x$ such that the equation is true).

This means that if we let $x^2+x=t$ as you did, then we want the two possible values of $t$ to be distinct. Call them $t_1$ and $t_2$. We want that the following two equations both have two roots, and that all of the roots are distinct:

$$x^2+x-t_1=0$$

$$x^2+x-t_2=0$$

The quadratic formula gives

$$x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4t_1}}{2}$$

$$x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4t_2}}{2}$$

This means we want $t_1\neq t_2$, and $$t_1,t_2 > -\frac{1}{4}$$

Note that this inequality is strict, since a determinant of $0$ would give a double root.

---

We can now return to the equation involving $a$. We want to find which $a$ allow the two roots of the following equation to satisfy $t_1\neq t_2$ and $t_1,t_2 > -1/4$.

$$t^2+at+4=0$$

We use the quadratic formula again:

$$t_1=\frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2-16}}{2}$$

$$t_2=\frac{-a - \sqrt{a^2-16}}{2}$$

Since we want two distinct real values of $t$, $a$ must have absolute value strictly greater than $4$, to ensure a strictly positive determinant.

We also want $a$ such that both of these inequalities hold:

$$\frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2-16}}{2} > -\frac{1}{4}$$

$$\frac{-a - \sqrt{a^2-16}}{2} > -\frac{1}{4}$$

The second inequality implies the first, so it's sufficient that the second holds. It's equivalent to

$$2a < 1 - 2\sqrt{a^2-16}$$

Clearly all values of $a$ greater than $4$ don't work. We're left with $a < -4$.

At $a=-4$, $$1-2\sqrt{a^2}-16 > 2a$$

Let $f(a)=1-2\sqrt{a^2-16}$ and $g(a)=2a$. Notice that $f(a)$ is greater than $g(a)$ at $a=-4$. The equation $f(a)=g(a)$ has no solutions (to see why, subtract one from both sides and square).  This means $f(a)$ never crosses $g(a)$, and since both functions are continuous on $a \in (-\infty, 4]$, we know that $f(a)$ is greater than $g(a)$ for all $a\leq -4$.

The values of $a$ such that there are four real and distinct roots are all $a$ such that $\boxed{a < -4}$.

---

This same method (using the quadratic formula first on $x^2+x=t$, then on $t^2+at+4=0$, doing casework at each step) can be applied to the other parts of your question. Good luck!

Comment: So for second case, we need $t_1>-1/4$ and $t_2<-1/4$?

Comment: That looks right :)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, graphing it:

Let $a=y$, then $(x^2+x)^2+y(x^2+x)+4=0$

$\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{4}-\left( x+\frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}+
\frac{4}{\frac{1}{4}-\left( x+\frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}}$

[image]

Comment: How are relating this graph to the cases asked in the question?

Comment: For $y>16.25$ there're two values of $x$, i.e. two real roots; for $y=16.25$, one double real roots $x=−0.5$; for $−4<y<16.25$, no real roots; for $y=−4$, two double roots $x=−2,1$; for$ y<−4$, four distinct roots. One disadvantage is unable to know the nature for complex roots.